# Why voting age seems to be stuck at 18 (relatively high)?

Tags: voting

According to this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voting_age#Alphabetical_list_of_countries), the vast majority of countries have a voting age of 18. In the same time, there are plenty of other actions a person can do before this age ([here](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/reference/checklists/checklist_at_what_age_can_i.html) and [here] for examples within US and NZ). E.g.:

- Age 12 – boat with an engine under 3.75kW (5hp)
- Age 16 – motorcycle up to 11kW and up to 125cc
- Age 16 - consent to medical treatment
- Age 10 – **being charged** for murder, manslaughter, rape and aggravated sexual assault
- Age 12 - **being charged** for other criminal offences

and many more.

This is clearly debatable, but many items in this list involve a greater level of maturity than casting a vote. Also, people are exposed to politics at a much younger ages (though TV, banners etc.) than 18.

Many laws apply to them and they cannot react through voting. Also, vote casting can be seen as a civil duty which can be learned earlier than later.

**Question:** Considering all above, why 18 seems to be a stop in the vote age lowering process virtually in all countries?

Comment: Because once you turn 18 you stop caring about the rights of teenagers. Therefore there is no one to fight for a lower voting age, except for political parties favored by the young. That's also the reason why alcohol is sold after 21 in the US.

Comment: And the age limit for being a child under Obamacare is 26, not to mention receipt of various social programs like housing and food assistance is unlimited.  (If you can't feed and house yourself, are you really an adult?)

Comment: *When is one mature enough to make a good political decision?* This question is completely based on personal opinion. Is age alone even a reliable indicator of political competence? But what other indicator could be used which doesn't discriminate against some politically relevant demographic? There is a lot to be discussed here. But this is a website for questions and answers. It is not a place for discussions.

Comment: @Philipp  there is some biological science around this related to brain development and risk taking.  Boys take longer, shocking I know.

Comment: This should be answerable...  Pretty easily actually

Comment: @Philipp - "good political decision"? I thought universal suffrage is not 
 so much about the quality of a political decision, but about the ability of having one. I bet that in many countries, many people do not know the basics of politics within their own countries ([random example](http://www.businessinsider.com/poll-many-americans-dont-know-basic-facts-about-government-2014-9)) and they can vote.

Comment: Out of box guess: Anyway low voter participation among young adults and high voter participation among retires. Thus threshold of 18 years is not so  contested. Additionally I think that most people political views mature later, thus are not so convinced that if they had voted as teens the world would be indeed a better place, so later don't see big problem.

Comment: There is a reason why the age for being charged for criminal offenses is so low: in countries where it's higher, there are criminal gangs recruiting children to do their dirty work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Undeveloped brains

There is a solid argument that people should not be able to vote until 25.  There is more and more evidence that the [brain is not fully developed until at least 25](http://mentalhealthdaily.com/2015/02/18/at-what-age-is-the-brain-fully-developed/).  Sixteen year olds may be allowed to drive, but their insurance rates are much higher until they turn 25.

One might argue that inclusiveness should override critical thinking ability.  We don't otherwise say that people who lack critical thinking shouldn't be able to vote.  However, the problem in this case is that the sixteen year old person may vote for things that a forty-six year old person might choose not to do.

#### Lowering the voting age to 18

The voting age in the United States used to be 21.  It was lowered to 18 by the [twenty-sixth amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-sixth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution).  One of the arguments in favor at that time was that eighteen year olds could be drafted into the army.  This was a responsibility that could be imposed on someone without their consent, and at the time, without their vote.  That could have also been fixed by raising the draft age, but they found it more feasible to lower the voting age.

The draft is different from most of your [Irish examples](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/reference/checklists/checklist_at_what_age_can_i.html), as it is a responsibility that society imposes upon adults.  That gave moral authority to the argument that the voting age should be lowered to match.

#### Other age limits

Two of your examples related to people being punished for choices they made.  In those cases, the child has made a choice to act as an adult.  Even then, it is generally optional whether the child is treated as an adult.  It's not an automatic result.  Also, society can't prevent children from committing crimes.  It can only choose how to respond.  And society often chooses a harsh response, as it has found that children who do commit crimes at a young age are also more likely to do so when older.

If 16 is old enough to vote, is it also old enough to draft?  Should the drinking age be reduced to 16?  Should every criminal be treated as an adult from 16 on?  Should we reduce the parental insurance coverage age back to 16?

Should we go farther?  Some of those ages are 10 and 12.  Should someone who is 10 be able to vote?  Able to drink, smoke, or take other legal recreational drugs?  Allowed to drive?  To draft?  To always be charged as an adult?  Get married?  To consent to sexual intercourse?  To sign binding contracts?

Should we keep going?  After all, there's nothing magical about the age of 10.  The argument that everyone subject to the law should be able to vote on it goes past that.  Decisions that politicians make today can affect children not yet born.  Some of the federal debt in the US is almost two hundred years old, less than fifty years younger than the US as a country.  No one alive now was old enough to vote when the debt was taken out.  Yet we are still bound by it.

You skipped over one of the examples.  There is no legal minimum age for paying tax.  Even a newborn infant has to pay tax on any income exceeding  the exemptions.  So should newborn infants be allowed to vote?  We could create a legalism that parents earn all money until a child turns 18, but overall, that would just complicate things.  As a practical matter, we limit how children can work until they are 18.

#### Adulthood

In the end, it's simpler than that.  We generally regard voting as an adult privilege.  Driving a boat or motorcycle is not an adult privilege, so we allow children to do those things.  We especially allow them to do so in places where it is not feasible to travel without driving.  Perhaps we'll raise those ages in the future, to 18 (adulthood), 21 (drinking age in the US), or 25 (insurance rates drop).  Perhaps we'll stop letting anyone drive on public roads and only allow computers to drive all vehicles.

Voting, binding to contracts, and joining the military are adult privileges that often go together.  Prior to 18, parents make such decisions for their children.  After, they can't.  We expect adults to make their own decisions.  The age of 18 is a compromise, but it's a natural one.  Should someone not old enough to sign a binding contract be allowed to bind others to a choice by voting?

Comment: I know it's not quite the distinction you're trying to draw, but across Europe, there are quite a lot of juristictions in which *drinking* alcohol at 16 is perfectly legal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_drinking_age. Using a brain function definition also suggests the need for a maximum voting age.