# What is the minimum age before your political views are considered well thought out and educated?

Tags: political-theory, identity-politics

I see a lot of the time people shut younger people down when arguing politics because they say that they aren't wise and educated enough to have these opinions. What age or education level do you think makes a political view seem well thought out and educated?

Comment: I'm sorry, but any answer to this question would wholly depend on each answerer's opinion. Off the top of my head I can't think of a way to make this a more objective question, but someone else might be able to.

Comment: Partial answer here: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/19211/why-voting-age-seems-to-be-stuck-at-18-relatively-high There's an argument that many people don't develop the ability to control impulses and make and evaluate long-term plans until they're in their mid-20s.

Comment: Some people live their entire lives and never achieve what I would call a well thought out and educated opinion on politics.   My grandmother on my mothers side always voted for the better looking candidate.   Many people vote based on morals or religion which they pick up at a young age and maintain.   I appreciate @jeffronicus comment, and voted it up, but I'm not sure it's accurate.  There's no definable point where understanding and voting intelligently begins and many people, I would say, never achieve it.

Comment: Since every country seems to have a minimum age for voting, and another minimum for holding office, this question seems demonstrably objective.

Comment: Arguing politics when young, (even allowing the premise of preemptive immaturity), is sometimes a good way to help the young to develop more considered opinions.  Discouraging such argumentation might therefore only serve to needlessly prolong their immaturity.

Comment: People tend to say that when they disagree with what is being said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no minimum age or "education level" to have the capacity to understand the world in which you live or to effect political change in this world; for example, [4-year-old superhero using his power to feed the homeless](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/austin-perine-alabama-4-year-old-superhero-using-his-power-to-feed-the-homeless/).

Whether another individual considers your views "well thought out" or not is that individuals' opinion.